# Como hacer petición desde flutter a pretty url

Tags: laravel, android-studio, flutter

Estoy tratando de hacer una petición desde flutter a mi pretty url en mi localhost pero no logro hacer la petición ya que flutter esta trabajando usando una maquina virtual. ¿Como debería hacer mi ptecición?

Comment: Bienvenido estás en SO en español por favor traduce tu pregunta

Comment: Arreglado, una disculpa.

Comment: usa la ip local , esto ya no es un problema de flutter, podría pasar en android /ios , etc, es un problema de conectividad.

Comment: Hola! Como podria usar la IP local junto con mi pretty url, por ejemplo 10.0.0.2.developer.test/api?